# MooTools: Parent object calls child method

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm starting a project where I'll be mainly developing front end GUI for a web application and decided to go with MooTools instead of jQuery for it's better OOP capabilities. However, while testing out I have encountered something weird from my point of view as a Java developer. Here is the problem:

```
var Parent = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Parent constructor call!");
    },
    show: function() {
        console.log("From Parent!");
    },
    someParentMethod: function() {
        console.log("Some parent method");
        this.show();
    }
});

var Child = new Class({
    Implements: Parent,
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Child constructor call!");
    },
    show: function() {
        console.log("From Child!");
    },
    display: function() {
        this.show();
        this.someParentMethod();
    }
});

var c = new Child();
c.display();
```

The output of this reads:

```
Parent constructor call!
Child constructor call!
From Child!
Some parent method
From Child!
```

Now I'm a bit confused here...shouldn't last line read "From Parent!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's how polymorphism is supposed to work. Even if you're calling a method defined in the Parent class, you are still in a Child **instance**, so the overridden method in Child is called.

Comment: OP: also, you are not Extending parent, you are mixing it in (via Implements). this will not allow you to do `.parent()` calls either

Comment: try `Extends: Parent,` and then in show, you can do: `this.parent();` to call to parent proto.